# List object to json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, provider

Hello there i'm new to flutter and there is this object that holds all products detail, so when a product is added to a cart I want it to store all details in json format is I can retrieve it on later times.

here is the items class

```
class Item {
String productName;
String productImage;
int productQuatity;
int productId;
double productPrice;
String productColor;
String productSize;

Item(this.productName, this.productImage, this.productQuatity, this.productId, this.productPrice, this.productColor, this.productSize);

  Map toJson() => {
    'id': productId.toString(),
    'productName': productName.toString(),
    'colors': {
      'type': productColor.toString(),
      'sizes': {'type': productSize.toString(), 'amount': productQuatity}
    },
  };
  }
```

this is also add item notify

```
class AddItemNotifiy extends ChangeNotifier {
 List<Item> listItem = [];
 List<FinalProducts> finalProducts = [];
  addItem(String productName, String productImage, int productQuatity, int productId, double productPrice, String productColor, String productSize) async {
  Item item = Item(productName, productImage, productQuatity, productId, productPrice, productColor, productSize);
   listItem.add(item);

   notifyListeners();
    }

   void removeItem(Item _item) async {
   listItem.remove(_item);
   notifyListeners();
   }

 void toJsonForm(Item item) async {
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String currency;
  List<String> myList = List<String>(listItem.length);
   for (var i = 0; i <= listItem.length - 1; i++) {
    myList[i] = listItem[i].toJson().toString();
   }
    sharedPreferences.setString('productList',myList.toString() );
    currency = sharedPreferences.getString("productList");

    print(jsonDecode (myList));

 }
}
```

the output is just like this

```
     [{_id: 2, productName: Updated name, colors: {type: grey, sizes: {type: m, amount: 10}}},{_id: 2, productName: Updated name, colors: {type: grey, sizes: {type: m, amount: 10}}}]
```

but I want it to be like this

```
 [
{
    Id: "2",
    colors: [
        {
            type: "black",
            size: {
                type: 46,
                amount: 2
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    Id: "2",
    colors: [
        {
            type: "red",
            size: {
                type: 46,
                amount: 2
            }
        }
    ]
},  
]
```

I used provider for state management also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jsonEncode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) to convert an object to a JSON string.

This should work:

```
var myList = listItem.map((el) => el.toJson()).toList();

// Save the list as a string
sharedPreferences.setString('productList', myList.toString());

// Convert the list to a JSON string
print(jsonEncode(myList));
```

Comment: hello there I just implement your suggestion and the out put is just like this.       ` [
{
    "Id": "2",
    "colors": [
        {
            "type": "black",
            "size": {
               " type": 46,
                "amount": 2
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Id": "2",
    "colors": [
        {
            "type": "red",
            "size": {
                "type": 46,
                "amount": 2
            }
        }
    ]
},  
]`

Comment: but I don't want the keys in the double quotes like   "id"

Comment: Hi @HaptomeHadush. Why that? You asked to store your data in JSON format. And in JSON format the keys must be surrounded by quotes. Reference: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Hi @Matthias so here is the thing the data is submitted like this (I used GraphQL)    that is why.                postOrder(
    
      products:[
        {_id: "2", 
          productName: "Updated name", 
          colors: {
          type: "grey", 
          sizes: {
          type: "m", 
          amount: 10}}}, 
        {_id: "2", 
          productName: "Updated name", 
          colors: {
          type: "grey", 
          sizes:
          {type: "m",
          amount: 12}}}],
  )
      
}

Comment: @HaptomeHadush - that's no longer JSON, but something that looks kinda like JSON.  You should probably fix the consumer of the data.